# Uncaught TypeError: cerrar is not a function. Tengo declarada esa función pero me dice que no es una función

Tags: javascript, css, html5

me sale este error en mi código cuando intento cerrar un modal sin bootstrap. [image: Este es mi modal] Cuando le doy clic al botón cancelar quiero que se oculte ese div pero no reacciona. Ya puse data-dismiss y lo intenté ocultar con jquery pero me sale dicho error.

```
<script>
function cerrar() {
    $("#validarDatosUserPass").hide()
}
```

```
<div class="wrapper fadeInDown">
```

```
<h2 class="active"> Acceso </h2>



<div class="fadeIn first">
  <img src="http://danielzawadzki.com/codepen/01/icon.svg" id="icon" alt="" />
</div>


<form>
  <input type="text" id="usuario" class="fadeIn second" name="login" placeholder=" Ingresa tu correo">
  <input type="password" id="contrasena" class="fadeIn third" name="login" placeholder="Ingresa tu contraseña">
  <input type="button" id="acceder" onclick="acceder()" class="fadeIn fourth" value="Acceder">
        <input type="button" id="cerrar" onclick="cerrar()" name="cerrar" class="fadeIn fourth"  value="Cancelar">
</form>

<!-- Remind Passowrd -->
<!-- <div id="formFooter">
  <a class="underlineHover" href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
</div> -->
```

Comment: muchas gracias, si funcionó tu solución :)

Answer (score 2):

Esto ocurre solo en algunos browsers pero es muy comun:

Intenta usar un nombre de funcion distinto de los id's declarados en el HTML.

En tu codigo JS tienes la funcion `cerrar`:

```
function cerrar() {
    $("#validarDatosUserPass").hide()
}
```

y luego en HTML `id=cerrar`

```
<input type="button" id="cerrar" onclick="cerrar()" name="cerrar" class="fadeIn fourth"  value="Cancelar">
```

Para evitar problemas usa para la funcion un nombre distinto, por ejemplo:

```
function clickCerrar() {
    $("#validarDatosUserPass").hide()
}
```

y luego en HTML

```
<input type="button" id="cerrar" onclick="clickCerrar()" name="cerrar" class="fadeIn fourth"  value="Cancelar">
```

**Nota:**

Esto ocurre debido a que algunos browsers adoptaron la recomendacion W3C sobre objetos globales asociados a elementos HTML, donde un elemento HTML con `id=accion` pasa automaticamente a mapearse como `window.accion` (HTMLElement), sobreescribiendo la definicion de tu funcion `accion()` (`window.accion()`) (named access objects)

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#named-access-on-the-window-object

**Nota adicional:**

Esto tambien aplica al atributo `name` en formularios, por ejemplo:

```
<form name='myform'></form>
```

podra ser accedido directamente desde javascript como `window.myform` sobreescribiendo cualquier otra definicion anterior de variable o funcion `myform`.

Comment: gracias si funcionó

Comment: De nuevo pls, si existe el ID "cerrar" es recomendable no tener una function "cerrar" ?? eso es ?

Comment: Eso es, puedes cambiar el nombre de la funcion o si quieres puedes cambiar el id y dejar el nombre de funcion. la idea es no producir el conflicto de nombres.